# NowJS - client/browser communication (wihout contacting "everyone")

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io, nowjs-sockets

It is possible to define (client-side): now.function = function(){console.log('test');}

... that is called by server using: everyone.function() - but can it be executed on specific client's browser only (using something like: everyone.onlyThisClient.function())?

It is possible to do that using this.now.function() in some cases
(nowjs.on('connect'(...) for example) - but is it possible to do the same
thing "outside" any other nowjs function/object?

Comment: You could in a higher scope have a array of `now` objects, and run `nows.push(this.now)` in the `connect` handler. Then you can access a specific `now` object anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by passing the clientId parameter and use it to call a function for specific user.

```
everyone.now.userRegister = function(params)
{
    user.register(everyone, this.user.clientId, params);
};

(...)

var register = function(everyone, clientId, params)
{
    nowjs.getClient(clientId, function()
    {
        this.now.afterUserRegister(false);
    });
}

exports.register = register;
```

Note - this is just one approach to execute function "locally". It's also possible to pass a callback function and execute it - this way it is not necessary to use nowJS to run the after-something event.